# Issue with modeling Facts table - don't know what do with the fact that one of the dimensions may happen many times

Tags: data-warehouse

I am doing an model for warehouse whose topic are car crashes.

I've a problem I don't know how to solve, that is - my fact is a Crash. I don't know how to think in terms of drivers. Issue is that crash can be either with a tree/on a parking (so there's only one driver) or with other driver (so there are two of them), or even there might be a case of a large highway crash with multiple drivers.

I'm not sure how to model it then, as I can't just put single Driver into my facts because of that, and I don't know how to proceed as I'm not sure how to get around that.

How can you deal with this? In normal databases it wouldn't be an issue, but here it feels tricky. My first thought is to create a table with the car crash participants, but how do I mark it? Can I even do that in warehouses?

Comment: The fact is a _car_ crash.

Answer (score -1):

Your fact table represents the event, which is a crash. One row per crash.

Your dimension tables each represent a set of attributes that describe that event/crash, and those rows are reusable by multiple events/crashes. If you have two drivers, you need two dimension rows from the one driver dimension table.

However, how to model this depends on whether the two drivers bear a different relationship to the fact of the crash. Let's pretend at a theoretical level that you can distinguish the roles of the two drivers. Perhaps something like responsible/non-responsible, first/second, left/right, north/south, older/younger, whatever... Sound crazy? That's because in this scenario, it is. These roles make no sense. But *if they did*, if a different role is assigned to each and there is only one per role, then you simply have two (or more) columns in your fact table, one for each role:

```
create table driver (driver_id number,
                     name, etc....)

create table crash (crash_date date,
                    responsible_driver_id number, --> pointer to driver dimension
                    innocent_driver_id number, --> pointer to driver dimension
                    etc...)
```

If it's a one-driver incident, one of those can be `NULL` (or more usually a pseudo dimension key like `-1` that maps to a special "no driver" dimension row).

But obviously to model 3 drivers this way you'd need 3 dimension keys, and to model 10 you'd need 10. It quickly becomes unmanageable and very hard to query properly once you get past 2, and non-sensical if there isn't a clear role distinction that dictates which driver is in which column. That is of course your situation with the crash concept.

So, since in your case there is no meaningful distinction of roles, particularly if there isn't a limit on there being only 2 drivers (what about 3-way collision)? Then you need a *bridge table* with a PK across two columns to set up a many-to-many relationship:

```
create table driver (driver_id number,
                     name, etc....)

create table driver_group (driver_group_id number, --> first col in PK
                           driver_id number --> pointer to driver. Also second col in PK
                           )

create table crash (crash_date date,
                    driver_group_id number, --> pointer to driver_group bridge
                    etc...)
```

This allows you to associate as many drivers as you need and doesn't require distinguish their individual roles. They all bear the same unspecified relationship to the event/crash. The downside is that the more you employ bridge tables, the more you end up "snowflaking" and that can have a negative impact on query performance. But that's a lot better than multiple columns to choose between if there isn't a real role distinction.

If you do this, it adds an extra step in loading facts, and an extra step in querying: your users must be careful not to change the granularity of their queries by joining through this bridge table and forgetting to aggregate facts properly (e.g., using `MAX` on quantifiable facts when grouping by crash before attempting `SUM` across multiple crashes).